# Need a way or BizTalk functoids that auto concatenate same tag text

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper

I have a BizTalk schema that outputs an XML file that contains  tag shown  as below:

```
<Narrative>
  <Narrative>for Peter D. Smith Travel to Hamburg</Narrative> 
</Narrative>
<Narrative>
  <Narrative>20/09/15 - 21/09/15 Client development meeting</Narrative> 
</Narrative>
<Narrative>
  <Narrative>with HLAG in Hamburg: airfare ^Approvers: Peter</Narrative> 
</Narrative>
<Narrative>
  <Narrative>D. Smith Gary M. </Narrative> 
</Narrative>
```

As it is a narrative therefore the number of lines of text varies. I am new to BizTalk. Any suggestions how to auto concatenate those text within the same tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the following output you do not need a functoid at all, just a schema that has the Narrative field repeating under the Narrative record and a map that maps the Narrative field.

```
<Narrative>
  <Narrative>for Peter D. Smith Travel to Hamburg</Narrative> 
  <Narrative>20/09/15 - 21/09/15 Client development meeting</Narrative> 
  <Narrative>with HLAG in Hamburg: airfare ^Approvers: Peter</Narrative> 
  <Narrative>D. Smith Gary M. </Narrative> 
</Narrative>
```

If instead you want the below then you need to use the [Cumulative Concatenate Functoid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267873(v=bts.10).aspx)

```
<Narrative>
  <Narrative>for Peter D. Smith Travel to Hamburg 20/09/15 - 21/09/15 Client development meeting with HLAG in Hamburg: airfare ^Approvers: Peter D. Smith Gary M. </Narrative> 
</Narrative>
```